# Kafka Connect JDBC Sink "schema does not exist"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I am tryin to sink data into postgresql with kafka connect but I am getting the error that the schema does not exist.

Is it possible that the name of the topic, that includes dots, makes the problem, because the error mentioned that the schema "logstash" does not exist, and this is the string till the first dot?

ERROR:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:568)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:326)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:196)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.sql.SQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: schema \"logstash\" does not exist
  Position: 14

    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:546)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: schema \"logstash\" does not exist
  Position: 14

    ... 12 more
```

Sink config:

```
{
  "name": "jdbc.apache.access.log.sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "topics": "logstash.apache.access.log",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://<IP_OF_POSTGRESQL>:5432/kafka",
    "connection.user": "kafka",
    "connection.password": "<PASSWORD>",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "pk.mode": "kafka",
    "auto.create": true,
    "auto.evolve": true,
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true"
  }
}
```

Schema (called with API):

```
{
  "subject": "logstash.apache.access.log-value",
  "version": 3,
  "id": 3,
  "schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"log\",\"namespace\":\"value_logstash.apache.access\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"clientip\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"verb\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"response\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"request\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"bytes\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null}]}"
}
```

EDITED:

I tried to create a new topic with underscores. It looks like the dots are really the cause of the error. Is there any solution I can avoid it or do I made a mistake in my configuration...?

Comment: FWIW, both `converter.schemas.enable` properties are not valid. 1) StringConverter doesn't have a schema 2) Avro always has a Schema and cannot be disabled

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a `RegexRouter` SMT to rename a topic to something without periods before the Sink action of the database write.